# Automatic species names in latex / command that does something differently the second time it is run

Tags: text-manipulation

In academic publications it is a rule of thumb that the first time you give a species name, you write the genus and species in full...and the second time you can abbreviate the genus.

First time:

Escherichia coli

second time:

E. coli

I wanted a latex way to do this automatically.  After some searching, I eventually came up with this, and I thought I'd share it..

```
%% Meta-Command for defining new species macros
\newcommand{\species}[4]{\newcommand{#1}{\ifdefined
    #2{\itshape #4}\xspace \else\newcommand{#2}{}{\itshape
    #3}\xspace \fi}
}

%% Defining new species
% The first argument is the name of the macro you will call in the document.
% The second argument is the name of a flag that is used to keep track of if this is the first time the macro is being called.
% The third argument is what is written the first time the macro is called
% The fourth argument is what is written every subsequent time the macro is called.

\species{\ecoli}{\ecolihbd}{Escherichia coli}{E.\;coli}
\species{\rsphaeroides}{\rspaheroideshbd}{Rhodobacter
  sphaeroides}{R.\;sphaeroides}
\species{\abrasilense}{\abrasilensehbd}{Azospirillum
  brasilense}{A.\;brasilense}
\species{\celegans}{\celeganshbd}{Caenorhabditis elegans}{C\;elegans}
\species{\pseudomonads}{\pseudomonadshbd}{Pseudomonads}{Pseudomonads}

%%

%%% Then later on, in the document:
\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because
people have studied \ecoli.
```

Output:

Escherichia coli is an example of a model species. People study E. coli because people have studied E. coli.

Answer (score 18):

You don't need the flag: just define the macro to print the complete name and then *globally* redefining itself to print the abbreviated name. The global definition is needed because the first appearance might be in a group (an environment, for instance).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}

%% Meta-Command for defining new species macros
\newcommand{\species}[3]{%
  \newcommand{#1}{\gdef#1{\textit{#3}\xspace}\textit{#2}\xspace}}

%% Defining new species
% The first argument is the name of the macro you will call in the document.
% The second argument is what is written the first time the macro is called
% The third argument is what is written every subsequent time the macro is called.

\species{\ecoli}{Escherichia coli}{E.~coli}
\species{\rsphaeroides}{Rhodobacter sphaeroides}{R.~sphaeroides}
\species{\abrasilense}{Azospirillum brasilense}{A.~brasilense}
\species{\celegans}{Caenorhabditis elegans}{C.~elegans}
\species{\pseudomonads}{Pseudomonads}{Pseudomonads}

%%

\begin{document}
\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because
people have studied \ecoli.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Clever! One should leave out `\xspace`, though. `\textit` will never find an exception from `\nocorrlist` and wrongly add `\/` in `\ecoli.` for example

Comment: @cgnieder That's in the nature of things: either use `\xspace` and forget about italic correction or use `\ecoli{}`.

Comment: This seems to choke if I use it in a title (TeX capacity exceeded); there a workaround?

Comment: @NickT Try `\protect\ecoli` in a title.

Comment: Renders, but also ignores my `\spacedallcaps`

Comment: @NickT There's no `\spacedallcaps` here; please, make a new question with a MWE.

Comment: @egreg excelent, but what can I do if every document section I have to write the full form?

Comment: @DanielValenciaC. Your wish is my command. `;-)`

Answer (score 13):

I would use [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries) for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym[first={Escherichia coli}]{ecoli}{E. coli}{Escherichia coli}

\begin{document}
\Gls{ecoli} is an example of a model species.  People study \gls{ecoli} because
people have studied \gls{ecoli}.
\end{document}
```

Creating a `\species` macro to create the `\newacronym` should be pretty straight forward. The `glossaries` package takes care of the first/subsequent usage automatically and also handles capitalization and pluralization. It also has nice features for creating lists of acronyms.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from egreg's answer, this example uses a different syntax to address the problem with xspace and italics correction. The species are defined using `\newspecies` and `\species` sets the species name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\speciesformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand{\newspecies}[3]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname species@#1\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname species@#1\endcsname{#3}%
    #2%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\species}[1]{%
  \speciesformat{%
    \@ifundefined{species@#1}{%
      \latex@error{Species `#1' is undefined}\@ehc
      [#1]%
    }{%
      \csname species@#1\endcsname
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newspecies{ecoli}{Escherichia coli}{E.~coli}
\newspecies{rsphaeroides}{Rhodobacter sphaeroides}{R.~sphaeroides}
\newspecies{abrasilense}{Azospirillum brasilense}{A.~brasilense}
\newspecies{celegans}{Caenorhabditis elegans}{C.~elegans}
\newspecies{pseudomonads}{Pseudomonads}{Pseudomonads}

\begin{document}
\textbf{\species{ecoli} is an example} of a model species.
People study \species{ecoli} because people have
studied \species{ecoli}.

\end{document}
```

Some remarks:

- The example uses `\textbf` for the first `\species` call to show, why the global redefinition is important here.
- The syntax makes package `xspace` obsolete. The suppressed italics correction can be seen in the last call of `\species` before the period.

> [image: Result]

---

The next example calculates the abbreviated form. If the long form consists of more than two word, the first word is abbreviated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\speciesformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newspecies}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname species@#1\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\speciesMakeShort\csname species@#1\endcsname#2 \@nil{#2}%
    #2%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
% Assumption: the first word consists of more than one letter.
\def\speciesMakeShort#1#2 #3\@nil#4{%
  \begingroup
    \def\x{#3}%
    \ifx\x\@empty
      % one word, no spaces
      \gdef#1{#4}%
    \else
      \species@MakeShort#1#2 #3\@nil
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\def\species@MakeShort#1#2#3 #4 \@nil{%
  \gdef#1{#2.~#4}%
}
\newcommand*{\species}[1]{%
  \speciesformat{%
    \@ifundefined{species@#1}{%
      \latex@error{Species `#1' is undefined}\@ehc
      [#1]%
    }{%
      \csname species@#1\endcsname
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newspecies{ecoli}{Escherichia coli}
\newspecies{rsphaeroides}{Rhodobacter sphaeroides}
\newspecies{abrasilense}{Azospirillum brasilense}
\newspecies{celegans}{Caenorhabditis elegans}
\newspecies{pseudomonads}{Pseudomonads}

\begin{document} 
\textbf{\species{ecoli} is an example} of a model species.
People study \species{ecoli} because people have
studied \species{ecoli}.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\species{rsphaeroides} & \species{rsphaeroides} \\
\species{abrasilense} & \species{abrasilense} \\
\species{celegans} & \species{celegans} \\
\species{pseudomonads} & \species{pseudomonads} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way. The command `\species` defines a boolean flag which will be set to `true` the first time a species is typeset. Depending on the status of the boolean flag either the long or the short version is typeset:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xspace}

\makeatletter
\def\stripbs{\expandafter\@gobble\string}
\newcommand*\species[3]{%
  \newbool{species@\stripbs#1@used}%
  \csdef{species@\stripbs#1}{%
    \ifbool{species@\stripbs#1@used}%
      {% subsequent times:
        {\itshape#3}\xspace
      }%
      {% first time:
        \booltrue{species@\stripbs#1@used}%
        {\itshape#2}\xspace
      }%
  }%
  \def#1{\csuse{species@\stripbs#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\species{\ecoli}{Escherichia coli}{E.\,coli}
\species{\rsphaeroides}{Rhodobacter sphaeroides}{R.\,sphaeroides}
\species{\abrasilense}{Azospirillum brasilense}{A.\,brasilense}
\species{\celegans}{Caenorhabditis elegans}{C\,elegans}
\species{\pseudomonads}{Pseudomonads}{Pseudomonads}

%%

\begin{document}

\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because
people have studied \ecoli.

\celegans is an example of a model species.  People study \celegans because
people have studied \celegans.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this version does not add italic correction (`\ecoli!`). IMHO it would be better to leave out `\xspace` and use `\textit{...}` in the definition.

Answer (score 3):

It's great that you've developed your own thing, but have you tried the [biocon](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biocon) package, by Pieter Edelman, before?
It's availble at CTAN, and does exactly what you're looking for (and it works, I've tried).

Another package available by the same author, useful for fellow biologists, is [dichokey](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dichokey), which provides typesetting for dichotomous identification keys.

Comment: This looks like exactly the package for the question. It would be nice if you added a small example of its usage to your answer!!

Answer (score 2):

I have previously used something like this for acronyms and stuff.

Here is a small snippet that can be used:

```
\newcommand\species[3][]{%
    \def\speciesname{\expandafter\@gobble\detokenize\expandafter{\string#2}}%
    % Create the full command
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname\speciesname full\endcsname{#3}%
    % This testing should be performed in other manners, however, it works...
    \def\tmpa{#1}%
    \def\tmpb{}%
    % Create the command \#2short thus you can always retrieve 
    % the short name
    \ifx\tmpa\tmpb%
      \expandafter\newcommand\csname\speciesname short\endcsname{#3}%
    \else%
      \expandafter\newcommand\csname\speciesname short\endcsname{#1}%
    \fi%
    % The command is created as such:
    %   1. First execute the "full" command
    %   2. Redefine the command to execute the "short" command
    \edef\tmp{%
    \noexpand\newcommand\noexpand#2{%
        \csname\speciesname full\endcsname%
        \noexpand\let\noexpand#2\expandafter\noexpand\csname\speciesname short\endcsname}%
    }\tmp%
}
```

This will let you do this:

```
\species[E. coli]{\ecoli}{Escherichia coli}
```

which makes `\ecoli` be Escherichia coli for the first time and then E. coli the second time. You then always have access to `\ecolishort` and `\ecolifull`. Notice that the shorthand argument is optional. If not set it will be the "full" no matter what. With this snippet you always have access to the full and the short version of the name (which I quickly found was very necessary!).

As egreg correctly points out there should be several globals around to ensure correct execution in groups.

So the following:

```
\species[E. coli]\ecoli{Escherichia coli}

\species\ecolib{Escherichia colib}

\ecoli\ and \ecoli\ and \ecolishort\ and \ecolifull.
\par
\par
\ecolib\ and \ecolib\ and \ecolibshort\ and \ecolibfull.
```

Will show this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/), so here's a solution using that.  What I do is define a new command `\acn` based on `\ac`, but instead of calling `\acf` internally to print *Full Name (FN)* on the first use, it calls `\acl`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acronym}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\acn}{\AC@starredfalse\protect\@acn}%
\WithSuffix\newcommand\acn*{\AC@starredtrue\protect\@acn}%
\newcommand{\@acn}[1]{%
\ifAC@dua
\ifAC@starred\acl*{#1}\else\acl{#1}\fi%
\else
\expandafter\ifx\csname AC@#1\endcsname\AC@used%
\ifAC@starred\acs*{#1}\else\acs{#1}\fi%
\else
\ifAC@starred\acl*{#1}\else\acl{#1}\acused{#1}\fi%
\fi
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newacro{ecoli}[\emph{E. coli}]{\emph{Escheria Coli}}

\acn*{ecoli}

\acn{ecoli}

\acn{ecoli}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Note that the starred version doesn't marked the acronym as used, which is why the second call still prints the long version.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add something to Daniel E. Shub's answer:

If you use the abbreviations from the glossaries package only for species names, you probably **do not want to generate a list of these abbreviations** (at least I don't). Hence, it is a bit annoying that the species names in the document are highlighted as hyperlinks when the hyperref package is used.

To solve this, one can add an option to disable the hyperlinks (see also section 6.2 of the Glossaries package's documentation):

```
\glsdisablehyper
\Gls{ecoli} is an example of a model species.  People study \gls{ecoli} because 
people have studied \gls{ecoli}.
```

To re-enable the hyperlinks, the option

```
\glsenablehyper
```

can be used.