# Reassignment macro doesn't work inside title, if protected "works" but not styled

Tags: macros, errors, classicthesis

A [handy macro egreg made](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71092/automatic-species-names-in-latex-command-that-does-something-differently-the-s/71094?noredirect=1#comment496822_71094) works famously, but not so well in titles. `\protect`ing it prevents TeX from dying, but then it seems to be hidden from `\spacedallcaps`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[nochapters,beramono]{classicthesis}

%% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71094/31523
\newcommand{\species}[3]{%
  \newcommand{#1}{\gdef#1{\textit{#3}\xspace}\textit{#2}\xspace}}

\species{\ecoli}{Escherichia coli}{E.~coli}
\species{\celegans}{Caenorhabditis elegans}{C.~elegans}
%%

\title{\spacedallcaps{Studying \protect\celegans eating \protect\ecoli.}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because
people have studied \ecoli. But \celegans is better.

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\title{\spacedallcaps{Studying \textit{Caenorhabiditis Elegans} eating \protect\ecoli.}}` replacing the other `\title`, it looks more as-intended

[image]

Comment: The species names should *always* be in italics. What do you think the output should be like?

Comment: In any case, the species' name appearing in the title shouldn't be considered the first appearance, so you should simply use the full name in a title.

Comment: You get letter spacing by adding `\lsstyle`: `Studying \textit{\lsstyle Caenor...}}`

Comment: another reason for not using any author-defined macro in a title is that, if the paper is to be published in a journal, many publishers provide copies of the contents (and often abstracts and bibliographies) to indexing services, and an unrecognized macro would compromise the usefulness of doing that.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using the species' name macro in the title, because it surely mustn't be considered the first appearance.

Having a macro in the title is to be avoided because publishers may want to use `\title` for automatically producing a Web page. In my opinion you shouldn't be using `\spacedallcaps` in the title, too.

If the paper is for personal use (probably it is, as no publisher would accept `classicthesis`), use `\lsstyle` and manually insert the species' names.

```
\title{%
  \lsstyle
  STUDYING \textit{CAENORHABIDITIS ELEGANS}
  EATING \textit{ESCHERICHIA COLI}%
}
```

or use `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[nochapters,beramono]{classicthesis}

%% from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71094/31523
\newcommand{\species}[3]{%
  \newcommand{#1}{\gdef#1{\textit{#3}\xspace}\textit{#2}\xspace}}

\species{\ecoli}{Escherichia coli}{E.~coli}
\species{\celegans}{Caenorhabditis elegans}{C.~elegans}
%%

\title{\lsstyle\MakeUppercase{%
  Studying \textit{Caenorhabditis elegans}
  eating \textit{Escherichia coli}}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because
people have studied \ecoli. But \celegans is better.

\end{document}
```

Beware also of using the macros in section titles. The problem is the same: an appearance there must never be considered the first one. If you have a table of contents you'd have some surprises.

[image]