# How to reset a macro every section? e.g. Macro that italizes a specie names

Tags: macros, sectioning, italic

I was looking for a macro that create automatically the italic name of species. I found [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71094/107689). Unfortunately, I have to write the complete form every document section. What I have to add to this macro for to write the full name when it is called for the first time in every section?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\species}[3]{%
\newcommand{#1}{\gdef#1{\textit{#3}\xspace}\textit{#2}\xspace}}

\species{\ecoli}{Escherichia coli}{E.~coli}

%%

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because
people have studied \ecoli.\par
\section{Section 2}
\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because
people have studied \ecoli.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to use something like `glossaries` instead of your own macros.

Comment: @HenriMenke I tryed to use `glossaries`, however I found it very difficult to run in Windows. It wasn't clear how to run `\makeglossaries`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Revamped version of my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71094/4427

The following code allows to reset the long form. The command `\resetspecies` can be called anywhere; if no optional argument is given, all species will be reset, otherwise only those specified as in the following example.

With `\xpreto{\section}{\resetspecies}`, all species will be reset at a new section (use `\chapter` if the resetting is to be done at chapters).

The notable difference with the previous version is that the macro name should be given without the backslash (for ease of implementation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xparse,xpatch}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% Meta-Command for defining new species macros
\NewDocumentCommand{\species}{mmm}
 {
  \daniel_species_define:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\prop_new:N \g_daniel_species_names_prop
\prop_new:N \g_daniel_species_used_prop
\prop_new:N \l__daniel_species_temp_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \daniel_species_define:nnn
 {% save the long and short forms in a property list
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_daniel_species_names_prop { long#1 } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_daniel_species_names_prop { short#1 } { #3 }
  % the long form is initially chosen
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_daniel_species_used_prop { #1 } { 0 }
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { #1 }
   {% if the value in the "used" property list is 0 use the long form
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \prop_item:Nn \g_daniel_species_used_prop { #1 } } = { 0 }
     {
      \textit { \prop_item:Nn \g_daniel_species_names_prop { long#1 } }
     }
     {
      \textit { \prop_item:Nn \g_daniel_species_names_prop { short#1 } }
     }
    % mark the species as used
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_daniel_species_used_prop { #1 } { 1 }
    \xspace
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\resetspecies}{ o }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {% reset all species
    \prop_clear:N \l__daniel_species_temp_prop
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_daniel_species_used_prop
     {
      \prop_put:Nnn \l__daniel_species_temp_prop { ##1 } { 0 }
     }
    \prop_gset_eq:NN \g_daniel_species_used_prop \l__daniel_species_temp_prop
   }
   {% reset only the specified ones
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
     {
      \prop_gput:Nnn \g_daniel_species_used_prop { ##1 } { 0 }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\xpreto{\section}{\resetspecies}

%% Defining new species
% The first argument is the name of the macro you will call in the document.
% The second argument is what is written the first time the macro is called
% The third argument is what is written every subsequent time the macro is called.

\species{ecoli}{Escherichia coli}{E.~coli}
\species{rsphaeroides}{Rhodobacter sphaeroides}{R.~sphaeroides}
\species{abrasilense}{Azospirillum brasilense}{A.~brasilense}
\species{celegans}{Caenorhabditis elegans}{C.~elegans}
\species{pseudomonads}{Pseudomonads}{Pseudomonads}

%%

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because
people have studied \ecoli. Also \abrasilense.

\resetspecies

\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because
people have studied \ecoli. Also \abrasilense and \celegans.

\resetspecies[ecoli,celegans]

\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because
people have studied \ecoli. Also \abrasilense and \celegans.

\section{Second}
\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because
people have studied \ecoli. Also \abrasilense and \celegans.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option for your implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace,etoolbox}

\newcommand{\setspecies}[4]{%
  #1{#2}{\renewcommand{#2}{\textit{#4}\xspace}\textit{#3}\xspace}}%
\newcommand{\species}[3]{%
  \setspecies{\newcommand}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \pretocmd{\section}{\setspecies{\renewcommand}{#1}{#2}{#3}}{}{}}

\species{\ecoli}{Escherichia coli}{E.~coli}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because people have studied \ecoli.

\section{Second section}
\ecoli is an example of a model species.  People study \ecoli because people have studied \ecoli.

\end{document}
```

The `\setspecies` macro can be called to *re*define how the species are set. It defines it upon a call to `\species`, and *re*defines it with every `\section`.